# Deep $watch vs $watchCollection: $var behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is `$watchCollection` able to ignore changes to properties that start with $?  This behavior already exists using a deep `$watch` since it relies on `angular.equals` for comparison.

Ideally, `$watchCollection` is the preferred (and only) way to shallow watch an object.  Is there a justification in the different behaviors?

*Example*

```
$scope.foo = {
  $bar: 'someValue',
  baz: 123456
};

$scope.$watch('foo', function() { 
   console.log('watch'); 
}, true);

$scope.$watchCollection('foo', function(){ 
   console.log('watchCollection'); 
});

// logs 'watch'
// logs 'watchCollection'
$scope.foo.baz = 654321;

// logs 'watchCollection'
$scope.foo.$bar = 'changed'
```

Comment: I believe `$watchCollection` is to watch arrayLike objects. `$watchCollection is the preferred (and only) way to shallow watch an object` ? i guess you could just use watch without 3rd argument to shallow watch.

Comment: @PSL watch without the 3rd argument only checks for object reference not equality.  so `var a = {};`  and `a.newProp = 1; `wouldn't trigger it since `a == a;` is still `true`.  And $watchCollection is also not limited to arrayLike objects ;(

Comment: ah i forgot about that...

Comment: I started an issue on github for this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10426

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the angular `$watch` source code comments:

> When `objectEquality == true`, inequality of the `watchExpression` is determined according to the {@link angular.equals} function.

We can see that from the `angular.equals` documentation:

> During a property comparison, properties of function type and properties with names that begin with $ are ignored.

So that explains why the $ properties are ignored for `$watch` comparisons.

The `$watchCollection` function actually does it's own comparison to check to see if the objects are the same, whether or not they're arrays and if they're arrays it checks to see if the values are the same. Taken straight from the source code:

```
if (oldLength !== newLength) {
    // if lengths do not match we need to trigger change notification
    changeDetected++;
    oldValue.length = oldLength = newLength;
}
// copy the items to oldValue and look for changes.
for (var i = 0; i < newLength; i++) {
    oldItem = oldValue[i];
    newItem = newValue[i];

    bothNaN = (oldItem !== oldItem) && (newItem !== newItem);
    if (!bothNaN && (oldItem !== newItem)) {
        changeDetected++;
        oldValue[i] = newItem;
    }
}
```

I can't speak to whether or not they implemented it that way on purpose, but that's certainly how it worked out =D

Comment: Thanks for this.  I found the one line I'd have to change to make $watchCollection behave similar but can't bring myself to modify the source code!

Comment: Haha yeah unfortunately it doesn't look like there's anything you can pass into `$watchCollection` that will get that behavior without actually modifying it.. I know the Angular team is pretty good at responding if you want to shoot them a pull request!